# Persistent Flash Message in cakephp version 2.2.2

Tags: cakephp-2.0

In my view I have:

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash();  ?>
```

In my UsersController I have:

```
public function login() {

        $this->Session->delete('Flash.auth');
        $this->Session->delete('Message.flash');
        $this->Session->delete('auth');
        $this->Session->delete('Message.auth');

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index')));
        } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, please try again', null, null);
            }
        }
public function logout() {

    $this->defaultTextView();

    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')));
    }

function index($id = null) {    
        $this->Session->delete('Message.flash');
        $this->Session->destroy('Message.flash');
        $user_id_sess = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
        $this->defaultAdminViewHere();
        $this->set('user_id_sess', $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'));
        $this->User->id = $id;
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read());    
    }
```

The problem is that my flash message persists even after a successful login.

pr($this->Session->read()); yielded:

```
Array
(
    [Config] => Array
        (
            [userAgent] => adcb84540c454620867cea3249a69ca1
            [time] => 1544388026
            [countdown] => 10
        )

    [Message] => Array
        (
            [flash] => Array
                (
                    [message] => Invalid username or password, please try again
                    [element] => default
                    [params] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Forced to add more details as my post is mostly code. It doesn't display the error message when I use the wrong password. It displays the error message after I log out.

Comment: It looks like you've randomly tried to delete various things from the session that you think might hold the message. From the code, it would appear that the thing you actually want to delete is probably `'flash'`, though that could be changed in your setup. Hard to say for sure, though, as 2.2.2 seems to predate any github history. Have you considered `pr($this->Session->read());` to see what's actually in there?

Comment: I tried to format my comment code with CTRL + K but it didn't work. Anyone know how I can format the code in my comment so that it's readable?

Comment: I have edited my code to add the comment.

Comment: It does look like `Message.flash` is what you want to delete; the other options can all go away to clarify things. Now, I believe that `$this->Session->flash('auth');` will show whatever is under the `auth` key, not `flash`, so that's probably not displaying anything? Perhaps you meant to use one of the other parameters to `setFlash` to specify the `auth` key instead of default `flash`? I'm also not quite clear on what you mean by `my flash message persists even after a successful login`; can you provide more detail on what you are seeing vs what you expect?

Comment: Even after the login form validates the error message remains. When I log in and then log out the error message is still there. I expect the error message to disappear after a successful login.

Comment: I disabled and cleared the cache and that didn't help.

Comment: If you `pr($this->Session->read());` and then `$this->Session->delete('Message.flash');` and then immediately `pr($this->Session->read());` again, is it in there the first time but gone the second?

Comment: I also tried:

$this->Session->delete('Message.flash');
$this->Session->delete('Message.flash.message');

but neither one of those worked.

Comment: Did you try print, delete, print all right in a row? Like, no page loads in between or anything, just three consecutive lines of code. If you do a delete and it's still there in the session right after that, then I don't know what it could be, that sounds like a failure at some fundamental level.

Comment: In my view I used: <?php echo $this->Session->flash();?> not with auth like I posted before.

Comment: It doesn't even display the error when I use the wrong password, it displays the error after I log out.

Comment: It seems like there might be some confusion on your side about how different flash keys work (e.g. flash vs auth), but that doesn't account for what you're seeing (or, at least, for what I'm understanding that you're seeing). Wonder if there's some bug related to this in that version of Cake? Is there some good reason that you're still on 2.2 instead of something from within the last 6 years? It's a big jump to go to 3.x, but getting closer to 2.10 shouldn't be all that painful.

Comment: Why did Rohit delete his answer?!

Comment: Just click on check you can accept the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash message works after minimum one redirect that's why you are getting this message. When you access this `login` action to display login form `flash message` sets but not getting print. After successful login this old flash message gets print because of one redirection. You need to write your login method something like this:

```
public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {

            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index')));

        } else {

            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, please try again', null, null);

            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I added the new redirect but that didn't work. I got the error message "[The website] redirected you too many times." It seems that the login page executes the else statement even if the login works.

Comment: Did you put the code inside `if ($this->request->is('post')) `?

Comment: I commented out my login method and just pasted yours in verbatim and the error message disappeared. The problem now is that the error message doesn't appear at all after I use the wrong password.

Comment: Also remove the `$this->Session->delete('Message.flash');
        $this->Session->destroy('Message.flash');` code from index page.

Comment: You should never need to manually delete flash messages from the session. You add them when you need to, and retrieve them for display in your layout; the act of retrieving them for display removes them from the session.

Comment: I removed the delete and destroy statements from the index page. It still doesn't display the error message when I use the wrong password.

Comment: Did you remove from the login also?

Comment: Yes, I removed them from the login.

Comment: try to write `$this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, please try again');` remove last 2 arguments.

Comment: is `<?php echo $this->Session->flash();  ?>` present in your login page?

Comment: I had <?php echo $this->Session->flash('warning'); ?> in my login page. I took out the word warning and now it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: I clicked on the up arrow to the left of your answer for "This answer is useful." Is that what you wanted me to do? Not sure what you're asking.